# Cannot Install Jupyter Conda

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I just did a fresh install of the latest version of Anaconda last night.

When creating a new environment for a Udemy class

`conda create --name Udemy_Jose pandas numpy scikit-learn jupyter`

it would hang - ran for an hour and no luck. I removed the environment and restarted. I found the culprit to be Jupyter. When I try `conda install jupyter` it runs and will hang and re-run, but runs into this error over and over:

```
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 0.163744 sec
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 0.232069 sec
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 0.445261 sec
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 0.846769 sec
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 1.65144 sec
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(226): retrying lexists(C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4\Library\doc\global\config.qdocconf) in 3.29855 sec
DEBUG conda.core.link:_verify_individual_level(191): Verification error in action LinkPathAction(target_prefix='C:\\Users\\matt\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Udemy_Jose', target_short_path='Library/doc/global/config.qdocconf', source_prefix='C:\\Users\\matt\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\qt-5.6.2-vc14_4', source_short_path='Library/doc/global/config.qdocconf', link_type=<LinkType.hardlink: 1>, _execute_successful=False)
DEBUG conda.core.link:_verify_individual_level(192): NoneType: None
```

I get the same error when i try `conda install qt`. So something must be wrong with this specific package. All I'm trying to do is install jupyter in my new environment... Or should i just [manually create the kernal for my environment?](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to make it easy to use new conda environments with Jupyter, I would suggest using the `nb_conda` conda package. Install it in your root environment and you should be able to access your other environments through the kernel dropdown in Jupyter.

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, Although I see my environment on the "Conda" Tab - It will not create a kernal that I can switch to on the kernel tab while in a notebook- any help on that? )The link you had provided did not address this issue)

Comment: Actually found a link that described this issue [here](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda). In short: you must install `ipykernel` in the environment to use it. Although your answer solves the "end-goal" of what I'm trying to do - still curious as to why `qt` is causing issues.